# How many times can a key be used for HMAC-SHA256 before it needs to be rotated?

Tags: hmac, key-rotation

If I wanted to use hmac for proving that a value hadn't been tampered with, how many times can I use a key before it needs to be rotated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no known inherent weakness in HMAC-SHA256 that requires key rotation for a suitably secret key.

However, other aspects of the system in which you are using HMAC-SHA256 may make key rotation necessary. For instance if you don't want the same message to have the same hmac over time for some reason a key rotation would achieve that (but so would a salt). Or if you know your key comes from an unusually low entropy pool making it easier to brute force than one would expect.

Comment: Thanks. So basically with a good key from something quality like `/dev/urandom` I should be good to go.

Comment: Yes. as long as your key isn't leaked via some other mechanism then 32 bytes from /dev/urandom would be a fine key.

Answer (score 0):

[With HMAC, can an attacker recover the key, given many known plaintext/tag pairs?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8500/with-hmac-can-an-attacker-recover-the-key-given-many-known-plaintext-tag-pairs?rq=1)

I guess this constitutes an answer. I can keep the key as long as I think I can keep it secure. Rotating the key would give me forward secrecy at least.